# Google Column Chart change color for each column with json

Tags: jquery, json, google-visualization

I´m trying to add a different color in each column, i have the following code to draw the chart:

```
var formDataKinder = {type:"Kinder"};
var jsonDataKinder = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data : formDataKinder,      
    url: "./content/chartsData.php",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
}).responseText;

var dataKinder = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonDataKinder);

var optionsKinder = {
    legend: 'none',
    chartArea: {'width': '80%', 'height': '80%'}
};

var chartKinder = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('Kinderchart'));
chartKinder.draw(dataKinder, optionsKinder);
```

I add the style in the array but the column do not change:

```
{"cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Grado","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Estudiantes","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","role":"style","type":"string"}
    ],
    "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"1ro.","f":null},{"v":8,"f":null},{"p":"color: #A22979","f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2do.","f":null},{"v":23,"f":null},{"p":"color: #1D63BB","f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"3ro.","f":null},{"v":32,"f":null},{"p":"color: #D72D16","f":null}]}         
]}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
{"cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Grado","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Estudiantes","pattern":"","type":"number"},
        {"id":"","role":"style","type":"string"}
    ],
    "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"1ro.","f":null},{"v":8,"f":null},{"v":"#A22979","f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"2do.","f":null},{"v":23,"f":null},{"v":"#1D63BB","f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"3ro.","f":null},{"v":32,"f":null},{"v":"#D72D16","f":null}]}         
]}
```

You can know the JSON structure of the DataTable by using `DataTable.toJSON()` after execute `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()`.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart